# Algorithm to detect spike in x y graph

Tags: python, algorithm

Imagine a realtime `x, y` graph where `x` is the quantity and `y` is time, with 1 minute interval. Every minute a new value is pushed in the graph. So I want to detect whenever there is a spike in the graph.

There are 2 kinds of spike:

1. Sudden Spike
2. Gradual Spike

Is there any way to detect them?

Comment: Sudden spikes can probably be detected. But "gradual" ones ??? In what way do they differ from a valid signal ?

Comment: what about a fourier transform and read frequencies small spikes are higher ftequencies and biger values slower canges.

Comment: You need to provide way more details:  What do the spikes look like (length, shape, height), what sort of noise is present, ...   BTW, having the time as `y` is very unusual, if this is really what you want, maybe you could tell us why.

Answer (score 4):

Since spikes are over a short distance (x2 - x1 ). You can take a [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples) for a *set of y values* over  a short range of x. If the deviation is reasonably large value, its a  spike.

For example for 9 consecutive y values

**4,4,5,10,26,10,5,4,4** standard deviation is **7.19**.

**4,4,5,10,100,10,5,4,4** standard deviation is **31.51**.

You can start by analysing the highest values of y and its neighbours.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the first derivative of y w.r.t. x using `numpy.diff`. Get a set of clean signals and obtain the threshold for it by obtaining the upper limit for derivative (this was the max deviation a clean signal had) using plain old `max(array)`.

Then you can subject your real time signal to the same kind of scrutiny, check for the derivative.

Also, you could threshold it based on the angle of the signal, but you would need a comprehensive sample size for that. You can use tan(signal) for this.

Different thresholds give you different kinds of peaks.

Adding to the suggestion provided, you could also calculate the standard deviation by `numpy.std(array)` and then checking for +- the value from the mean. This would of course, be better seen using the derivative as I mentioned.

A method used in financial analysis is Bollinger Bands. This link can give you more information about it : http://sentdex.com/sentiment-analysisbig-data-and-python-tutorials-algorithmic-trading/how-to-chart-stocks-and-forex-doing-your-own-financial-charting/calculate-bollinger-bands-python-graph-matplotlib/

They are basically the moving average over a period of a time series. You can get a better set of thresholds using them rather than just the standard deviation.